# linq one liner to remove elements from IDictionary whose keys are not in another Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, dictionary

I have

```
IDictionary<string,object> d1;
Dictionary<string, object> d2;
```

I need to remove from d1 all entries that are not in d2.

I know I can do this with a for loop etc but that's so last century; I want to do it right.

I got to

```
   d1.Where(x => {return d2.ContainsKey(x.key);});
```

but dont know what to do next

Comment: If you really want to do it right, just use a loop. It makes no sense to use LINQ here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ isn't designed to *modify* existing elements - but you could always create a *new* dictionary. For example:

```
d1 = d1.Where(x => d2.ContainsKey(x.Key))
       .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Or:

```
d1 = d1.Keys.Intersect(d2.Keys)
       .ToDictionary(key => x.Key, key => d1[key]);
```

As others have said, if you're more keen on doing a `Remove` operation, I'd just loop. For example:

```
foreach (var key in d1.Keys.Except(d2.Keys).ToList())
{
    d1.Remove(key);
}
```

(I'm not sure why you used a statement lambda in your sample code, by the way.)

Comment: Hi Jon, I read your book and value your opinion as a programmer and I was wondering what's your opinion on my answer, mainly, why you do not agree with it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum [This is Eric Lippert's reasoning](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).  My guess is Jon agrees.  Basically; avoid causing, and especially relying, on side effects of functions when using functional design (which is what LINQ is).  Technically, your solution isn't actually using LINQ beyond the use of `Where` and `ToList`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Yes, I very rarely like using `ForEach`. I would loop instead.

Comment: @Servy interesting, makes me wonder why PLINQ has this sort of functionality though.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Parallel Extensions does, but I wouldn't call that particular part PLINQ :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I tried doing the d1 = d1.where but could not work out the correct incantation. Thx. Ps why full lambda? Becuase I havent internalized the rules of when I need them and when I dont

Comment: i would like to mark two answers as correct, but cannot. I like this one because it shows the ToDictionary and says replace rather than modify in place. Unfortunately I cannot replace (the place where I got the dictionary from doesnt all me to replace it)

Comment: @JonSkeet Does removing from the IDictionary not cause an exception due to the collection being modified in your example with a foreach? I've always known removing from a collection within a foreach loop to be a bad idea, am I incorrect in that belief or is the IDictionary an exception?

Comment: @LeonNewswanger: Nope, because I'm collecting all the keys *into a list first*. I'm not iterating over the dictionary while I'm removing from it.

Comment: @JonSkeet so if you were iterating over the dictionary keys themselves and not the list, this would indeed throw an exception? Sorry, I typically avoid foreach iteration in these types of situations because of this exact confusion I'm having.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger: Yes, I believe so.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is for querying.  The information you're *querying* is the keys from `d1` that are not in `d2`.  Other than missing a `NOT` (unless you didn't mean to say "not" in your requirements). you already have that.  When it comes to actually *doing* something, that's best done with a `foreach` loop, not LINQ:

```
foreach(var pair in d1.Where(x=> !d2.ContainsKey(x.Key)).ToList())
{
    d1.Remove(pair.Key)
}
```

Note that the `ToList` is needed to ensure that you are not modifying a collection while iterating it.

Comment: this one, although not a one liner, is a nice working compromise (I cannot do the d1 = d1.Where that Jon suggests cos d1 is only readable by me

Comment: @pm100: You might still want to consider the `d1.Keys.Except(d2.Keys)` version from my answer. It does require building an extra hash set, but I personally think it's clearer.

Comment: @JonSkeet I was just about to point out that it needlessly creates the extra hash set as the key difference between the two ;)  If I were writing this I'd probably call `Where` on `Keys`, rather than using the pairs, but I wanted to use the OP's code specifically to demonstrate that he did most all of the work (correctly) on his own.